# org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions is only dependency not found in elasticsearch client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

For some bizarre reason, the following import is not being found by maven. I am not sure if it's removed from the dependency I get from maven or not. Could I please get a look at why it's not being found

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions;
```

I am using elastic version `6.3.2` with the high-level JAVA REST client as `6.3.2` also. My `POM` looks like this below.

```
         <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
                    <version>6.3.2</version>
                </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RequestOptions` was [introduced in version 6.4](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/breaking-changes-6.4.html#_old_high_level_request_methods_deprecated) of the Rest High-Level client.

So you need to upgrade your client to 6.4.0 at least. That version might work with ES 6.3.2 but there might be some [incompatibility issues](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.4/java-rest-high-compatibility.html) as only forward compatibility is guaranteed.

> The High Level Client is guaranteed to be able to communicate with any Elasticsearch node running on the same major version and greater or equal minor version.

Comment: Are there any work arounds for this Val. I am using 6.3.2 at the moment and the only import failing is RequestOptions?

Comment: Don't use RequestOptions since it's not available in your dependency :-)

Comment: I just tried it and it worked Val. Thank you. I have another question but I will open up another one. Thank you a bunch! I have marked your answer also!

Comment: Hey Val can you also assist with this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62092012/correct-the-classpath-for-compatible-versions-with-elasticsearch

Comment: Can you assist with this question also Val https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62122439/elasticsearch-method-not-being-found-in-spring-boot