# Elasticsearch method not being found in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient, elasticsearch-rest-client

I have been stuck with this issue for a while now and any assistance is appreciated. I am running Spring Boot version `2.2.0` with the ElasticSearch high-level REST Client version `6.4.3` and using version `3.2.0` for the Spring-Data-Elasticsearch version. I am getting the error below. I have tried the following attempts to fix but none do.

1. Change Spring Boot Version multiple times
2. Change ES version multiple times
3. I have cleared my .m2 folder and redownloaded the maven dependencies multiple times.

The issue I am getting below is

**An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:**

> org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.putMapping(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:292)

**The following method did not exist:**

> org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.putMapping(Lorg/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/mapping/put/PutMappingRequest;Lorg/elasticsearch/client/RequestOptions;)Lorg/elasticsearch/action/support/master/AcknowledgedResponse;

The method's class, org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient, is available from the following locations:

> jar:file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/6.4.3/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.4.3.jar!/org/elasticsearch/client/IndicesClient.class

It was loaded from the following location:
    file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/6.4.3/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.4.3.jar

Action:
**Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient**

My POM is below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help is appreciated. I am sure it has to deal with compatibility issues but not sure which. Thanks all!

### Update

I was able to get it run sucessfully by changing my elasticsearch version to `6.7.0`. But now I am receiving the following error

```
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=index_not_found_exception, reason=no such index]
```

My POM looks like this below now also.

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.70</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.70</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.70</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: which elasticsearch version you are using, you can get it from curl localhost:9200, on the elasticsearch server.

Comment: check update please @PrernaGupta

Comment: Glad you were able to now run the code and this exception is different, I would write a answer for previous issue and would advise to ask a followup question with relevant details(code which is causing the `index_not_found_exception ` ) and would be more than happy to help you with this required information.

Comment: should I open up another question @PrernaGupta for the new error I am getting?

Comment: Yeah please and ping me the question link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous issue of `method that does not exist.` was resolved by changing the elasticsearch version to `6.7.0`.

**To avoid these incompatibility issues its always recommend to use the same version of elasticsearch server and its client.**

Comment: Thank you Prerna. Please make sure your versions match up or you will receive compatibility issues.

Comment: @CodeMonkey glad it was helpful and waiting for your followup question.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue, I was using elastic search 6.8.18.
and as mentioned changed the version of elastic search by using below in Gradle.

```
ext['elasticsearch.version'] = '6.8.18'
```

use this for reference - [overriding dependency versions](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot)